# "Normalize" HTML table with rowspan

Tags: html, html-table

Is there a way to determine or calculate if and how a HTML table can be normalized using rowspans? Or if there is a JavaScript library that can do it.

E.g., this table:

```
+-----------+---------+
| Apple     | Red     |
| Apple     | Green   |
| Apple     | Yellow  |
| Sun       | Yellow  |
| Sun       | Hot     |
| Charizard | Hot     |
| Charizard | Pokémon |
+-----------+---------+
```

Would be turned into this:

```
+-----------+---------+
| Apple     | Red     |
|           | Green   |
|           |---------|
|-----------| Yellow  |
| Sun       |-------- |
|-----------| Hot     |
|           |---------|
| Charizard | Pokémon |
+-----------+---------+
```

Look at this fiddle to see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/scorch/LZKkQ/

Some of these combinations are easy to figure out manually, but some can be quite complex. I would like to minimize the table as much as possible, and be sure that there is no other combination that could minimize it further. I.e., preferably only unique values in the table.

**EDIT**: Never mind the extra column in the fiddle. Seems Firefox has some problems with rowspan on the right-most column, so I had to add another one for it to have the desired effect.

**EDIT 2**:

The DataTables plugin `fnMultiRowspan` and `fnFakeRowspan` mentioned below doesn't really get the desired results. Both plugins needs the table to be sorted in the right way beforehand to work; `fnFakeRowspan` only works on one column and `fnMultiRowspan` gives the result below (hot and yellow are duplicated in the second column):

```
+-----------+---------+
|           | Red     |
| Apple     | Green   |
|           | Yellow  |
|-----------+---------|
| Charizard | Hot     |
|           | Pokémon |
|-----------+---------|
| Sun       | Yellow  |
|           | Hot     |
+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: have you tried writing it yourself?

Comment: Yes, there is a jquery library [Datatable](http://datatables.net) that had this feature see this: [Visually grouping two or more cells in a row with the same content](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnFakeRowspan)

Comment: I've tried to find a mathematical way to do it, but I can't seem to find a way to make an equation out of it.

Comment: The expected output does not make sense. Where are the sun-yellow and Charizard-hot rows?

Comment: From an accessibility point of view, you can and should associate data cells with header cells in complex data tables like those with col/rowspan. It's done with **`id/headers`** in a similar fashion to for/id in forms. See [WCAG 2.0 Technique H43](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H43.html) for more information. That'll add work to the algorithm but as you'll already be looping through the table...

Comment: @SalmanA take a closer look - the rows overlap. It's not too obvious though and i wonder if this is useful but these relations are still present.

Comment: Your last column *is* necessary to create the effect you're going for (rowspans need rows to span, after all), but this is cumbersome to read and discern. I'd suggest against it.

Comment: I've notices wikipedia has some of these types of tables, though now I can't find an example, so I don't know if it's a metawiki thing or if it's done manually.

Comment: I was going to write this as an answer, but I didn't have the time to fully flesh out this idea. If you don't mind nested tables, you could try making each column have a nested table and make each row have a specific height. You could then count the number of times a string appears in the left row and set that as the rowspan. But, the table already has to be ordered as the first table.

Comment: @PaulSham: Sounds like an idea, but I guess it would be pretty hard to align it if the text in some of the rows are a bit too long so they get wrapped.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal It looks to me like your comment is actually a good answer, why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @DavidJames, I don't know really whether it is qualified to be an answer or not. The reason I didn't post it as an answer is that I didn't try it myself and I am not sure If this would be helpful and that's what the OP looking for or not, and it is working fine like the OP wants. Furthermore I had no responses about it except from you, So I felt it is off topic. I won't post it as answer because it is better to be a comment than an answer, But thanks for the tip and if you want to post it as answer go ahead.

Comment: This type of data visualisation seems similar to venn diagrams. Perhaps algorithms suited for that type of data visualisation could be employed? Or perhaps simply using a venn diagram instead of a table would be a better option in the event of 3 or more relationships between entries?

Comment: Immpossible. It's HTML (A markup language or a framework in HTML5), not RDBMS!

Comment: What if Yellow were in Charizard also? How would it look then?

Comment: @ThinkingStiff Yeah, then I'd accept duplicates of yellow, since it's not really possible. Hence the "**if** and how a HTML table can be normalized" and "I would like to minimize the table **as much as possible**" in the question.

Answer (score 2):

As @MahmoudGamal mentioned above in the comments, there is plug-in for jQuery called [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) that may be useful. Check out the [fnFakeRowspan](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnFakeRowspan) function:

> Creates rowspan cells in a column when there are two or more cells in a row with the same content, effectively grouping them together visually. Note - this plug-in currently only operates correctly with server-side processing.

Based on a quick code read, it looks like you specify a column, then it looks for duplicates, and combines cells as needed. (Note: I have not tried this code myself.)

Comment: Hm, it gets about halfway. I've tried it, and it only supported doing it to one column, not multiple. And also the table must be sorted in the exactly right order beforehand for it to work. There were some variations of the plugin on the forums, but none really did the job. Thanks anyway though, might have a look at it and see if I can get it to do what I want with some modifications.

Comment: NO, it supports for multiple column. but you have to call the `fnFakeRowspan()` once again.

Answer (score 0):

it would be simple to write it yourself if you understand JavaScript enough.  All you need to do is check if the next string is the same as the current string and then to just increase the height of one instead of printing it twice.

Edit: So you'd want it to end up like

```
+-----------+---------+
| Apple     | Red     |
| Pokémon   | Green   |
| Sun       | Yellow  |
| Charizard | Hot     |
+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: Well, it also has be be sortet first. And not just `column1 asc, column2 asc`, because that might not be the optimal way to arrange it (as in the example table above), since the second column also needs to be rowspanned. A more optimal arrangement could be made by moving the rows about after an initial sorting.

Comment: Not really. Check the "Would be turned into this:" table in the question.